# How to process Java8 stream of characters by maintaining a state

Tags: java-8, java-stream

```
public class StreamStringCompression {
    private Iterator iterator;

    public StreamStringCompression(Iterator iterator) {
        this.iterator = iterator;
    }

    public String encode(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
        return str;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "aaaabbcaaa";
        StreamStringCompression encoder = new StreamStringCompression(Collections.singletonList(str).iterator());
        str.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char)i).map(i -> encoder.encode(""+i));
    }
}
```

I have the above Java example, and I want to print the stream of characters such a way that it should print like below.

```
1a
2a
3a
4a
1b
2b
c
1a
2a
3a
```

How can I do this with java8 streams by maintaining a state?

Comment: It seems like this task doesn't fit well in the concept of pure functions.

Comment: Why don't you do it will plain loops?

Comment: I have the requirement to do the processing in streaming manner

Comment: If you have a requirement to apply functional programming to your problem you have to be familiar with its core concepts. That is the definition of the [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).

Comment: The pure function always produces the same result for the same input and doesn't cause side effects. In your problem maintaining an index for each group of symbols requires to store this information somewhere outside the stream. And it will be accessed and changed from the function in your pipeline, i.e. this function will cause side effect.

Comment: Isn’t a compression supposed to replace, e.g. `aaaa` with just `4a`? What would be the point of replacing it with `1a2a3a4a`? It seems, you have a habit of inserting parts of (flawed) solution attempts into your problem description. Like “by maintaining a state”. Or starting by creating a class requiring an `Iterator` without having any use for it. Further, your requirement “processing in streaming manner” mentioned in a comment is not the same as using a “stream of characters” as mandated by your question’s title.